# How to render fields in form?

Tags: 7, forms

I passed the `$uid` as a `hook_menu()`-wildcard to a form and loaded the user of that uid with `$account = user_load($uid)`. Admin then is able to fill some textfields and save. I want some other non editable fields from $account simply to be displayed as markup or anything like that in the form. Tried to pass these fields to #markup like so:
`'#markup' => $account->field`.

But this doesn't work. Should this normally work? What am I doing wrong?

Or would it be better to display an aditional block which fetches the $uid from the URL and prints me my fields?

Comment: Can you show us the code that isn't working, or at least the relevant portions?

Comment: @MPD - I was the one who flagged that question. The code that isn't working is in the question. And the question already got answered. It was a stupid question, cause I just didn't got the nested array. Please delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your approach. `'#markup' => $account->field` should work. Do you have it nested under a key?

```
$form['static_field'] = array(
    '#markup' => $account->field
);
```

Comment: Oh my! I'm so blind! An hour of trying. Thank you! `$account->field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` is the solution.

Comment: Ah yes, if it's a custom field, and not a core field, then yeah - they'll be nested like that. Glad you found it!